# Redirecting to another view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm trying to build a link shortener. The intended behavior is that on the first page (new) the user inserts his long link and presses a button, then he gets redirected to an another page called result, where a preset message will be waiting for him, along with both his short and long link.

I'm struggling with controllers, however, as no matter what I do something always comes wrong. Right now my controller looks like this:

```
    class UrlsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @short_url = Url.new
  end

  def create
    @short_url = Url.new(url_params)
    if @short_url.save
      flash[:short_id] = @short_url.id
      redirect_to "/urls/result"
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    Url.find(params[:id])
    #@short_url_yield =
    redirect_to @short_url.url
  end

  def result

  end

  private

  def url_params
    params.require(:url).permit(:url)
  end

end
```

And the routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :urls, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :result]
  get 'urls/result' => 'urls#result'
  root to: redirect('/urls/new')
end
```

When I submit the link, however, rails returns the following error:

```
Couldn't find Url with 'id'=result
Extracted source (around line #17):

def show
Url.find(params[:id])
#@short_url_yield =
redirect_to @short_url.url
end
```

It seems I don't understand the logic behind it. What's going wrong? Isn't the show bit supposed to be a redirect that happens when I click the shortified link?

Comment: can you please post the view from where you are calling shortified link

Answer (score 1):

Rails routes have priority in the order they are defined. Since your SHOW route declaration is before get `'urls/result' => 'urls#result'` the url gets matched as `/urls/id=result`.

Simply move your custom route above the resources block or use a collection block.

```
resources :urls, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :result] do
  collection do
    get 'result'
  end
end
```

Using the [`collection` and `member`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) blocks tells Rails to give priority to the routes inside over the normal CRUD actions such as show.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, another idea for a workaround is like this `resources :urls, :only => [:show, :new, :create, :result], id: /\d+/` This assumes your url ids are all numbers.

Comment: Yeah or you can just use `collection` - which is actually better since you do not make assumptions about the primary identifier.